# TypeScript: Can you abstract a static constructor method to return the inheriting class?

Tags: typescript, x12

## Question

See title

## Background

I'm trying to implement a document parser, and it is a delimited file in which the first element of a row is the heading for what type of data is within the row. I have set up a set of classes that represent these different data segments, and they all inherit from `Segment` as a base class, and there is a superclass of `SegmentPair` when a segment indicates the start of a larger data set than just the current row.

## Code

I'm trying to define a function that can be mapped across the 2D-array of values, like so (simplified version):

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const contents = readFileSync('x12.txt', 'utf-8');
const segments = contents.split(segmentDelimiter).map((segment: string) => segment.split(recordDelimiter));

const parsed: ISegment[] = segments.map(Document.segmentMapper);
```

As you can probably tell, `ISegment` is an interface implemented by `Segment`. I've also defined `Document` as `class Document extends Segment` which may or may not be a good design choice, but these definitions look somewhat like this:

```js
// ./interfaces/ISegment.ts
export interface ISegmentConstructor {
  new(segment: string, delimiter: string): ISegment;

  segmentMapper(delimiter: string, segment: string, index: number, array: string[]): ISegment;
}

export interface ISegment {
  get header(): string;

  get parts(): string[];
}
```

```js
// ./Segment.ts
import { StaticImplements } from 'common';

import { ISegment, ISegmentConstructor } from '../interfaces';

@StaticImplements<ISegmentConstructor>()
export class Segment implements ISegment {
  protected readonly delimiter: string;
  readonly raw: string;
  
  constructor(segment: string, delimiter: string) {
    this.raw = segment.trim();
    this.delimiter = delimiter;
  }

  static segmentMapper<T extends Segment>(delimiter: string, raw: string): T {
    return new Segment(raw, delimiter) as T;
  }
}
```

I didn't mention it before (forgot until now) but there's an intermediate class that extends `Segment` called `ControlSegment`. The only difference is that it has a `controlNumber` property, since some segments (usually pairs) have a checksum of some sort that validates they belong together.

```js
// ./SegmentPair.ts
import { ISegment } from '../interfaces';
import { ControlSegment } from './ControlSegment';
import { Segment } from './Segment';

export class SegmentPair<T extends ControlSegment> extends ControlSegment {
  protected footer: T;
  protected readonly body: ISegment[];
  protected readonly bodyMap: Map<string, number[]>;

  constructor(segment: string, delimiter: string, body?: ISegment[], footer?: T) {
    // implementation details
  }

  extend<S extends this>(raw: string, index: number, array: string[]): S {
    // more implementation details
  }
}
```

Anyway, `Document.segmentMapper` is a very lengthy method, since it contains switch-case that maps each segment header to a class constructor. The static constructor pattern I chose was a common method `segmentMapper` that expects `segmentMapper(delimiter: string, segment: string, index: number, array: string[]): Segment` to match the rough signature of a call to `Array<string>.prototype.map<ISegment>()`. An excerpt of this code is as follows:

```js
import { ISegment } from './interfaces';
import { Segment } from './Segment';
import { SegmentISA } from './SegmentISA';
import { SegmentTRN } from './SegmentTRN';

export class Document extends Segment implements ISegment {
  segments: Segment[];
  private segmentMap: Map<string, number[]>;
  
  constructor(raw: string) {
    const [ segments, segmentDelimiter, recordDelimiter ] = Document.detectDelimiter(raw);
    super(raw, segmentDelimiter);
    this.segmentMap = new Map<string, number[]>();
    this.segments = segments.map(this.segmentMapper.bind(this, recordDelimiter));
  }
  
  private static detectDelimiter(raw: string): [ string[], string, string ] {
    // implementation details
    return [ raw.split(segmentDelimiter), segmentDelimiter, recordDelimiter ];
  }

  segmentMapper(delimiter: string, segment: string, index: number, array: string[]): Segment {
    const [ header ] = segment.split(delimiter);
    const lookup = this.segmentMap.get(header) ?? [];
    lookup.push(index);
    this.segmentMap.set(header, lookup);
    
    switch(header) {
      case 'ISA':
        // Herein lies the problem (see explanation below)
        return SegmentISA.segmentMapper(delimiter, segment).extend(segment, index, array);
      case 'TRN':
        return SegmentTRN.segmentMapper(delimiter, segment);
      default:
        return Segment.segmentMapper(delimiter, segment);
    }
  }
}
```

## Problem

So, this pattern is extremely verbose (there's 24 cases), but I'm not too bothered by long code as long as it's clean and easily understood. The problem I have is the `SegmentISA.segmentMapper()` returns a type `Segment` rather than `SegmentISA`, and `Segment` doesn't have the `extend` method that comes from `SegmentPair`.

How do I implement a static constructor method (like `segmentMapper`) that returns the inheritor's class rather than the implement's class? I know I could just write an override implementation at the inheritor's level, but I was hoping there would be a way to enforce it with less code. You can see I've added the type parameter to `static segmentMapper<T extends Segment>` as an ugly solution (IMO). I'm thinking I might implement a `SegmentFactory` class that has getters that return the typed segment so I can eliminate the switch-case and use something closer to `import segmentFactory from './SegmentFactory'; const segment = segmentFactory[header](delimiter, segment, index, array);` but I wanted to pose the question to the community.

Comment: Note: if you want to pretend something is X12, you can take any CSV and the record delimiter is `\n` while the segment delimiter is `,` or whatever delimiter was provided. X12 is much stricter in what can be where, but it's a delimited flat file at its core. From what I've seen, X12 seems to be row-delimited by `~` and column-delimited by `*`

Comment: To answer the question: Not possible. Change your approach. Handle envelopes on their own. Parse the segments inside the transaction set, then wrap that with the ST, GS, and ISAs. Re EDI: You are going to hit bigger problems when you get to LS/LE segments, HL, looping contexts, composite elements, and repeat segments and elements. The trick is to write a parser that tracks minimal context. X12 is not just rows and columns, it can represent incredibly complex structures. It takes years to understand the spec. Have you thought about using an API that converts between JSON and EDI for you?

Comment: @RossWilliams no, I haven't looked into an existing API. I maintain an internal library of QA utilities to be used in automated testing, and inherited the existing codebase. The original "parser" basically split the file by segment and record delimiters and then encapsulated the 2D-array. I'm trying to improve that code to be more descriptive of the actual document. I'm also going reducing dependencies as we've been had on numerous occasions in the last year, between `colors.js` and removing `lodash`. I.e. I just finished implementing the Node-native HTTP/S module to remove `request-promise`.

Comment: It sounds like you are in a difficult situation. It would be a lot easier to test the inputs to EDI Translation and trust that your EDI Translate service or software package will get it into the correct EDI shape.

Comment: It may be easier to handle if you get it into JSON first. Here's an example of what JSON EDI structure looks like: https://www.stedi.com/edi/inspector?view=json